# gedit bug (?) on replacing newline character

Tags: 16.04, gedit

I accidentally used the wrong-sided slash when trying to write the Newline (Line Feed) escape character, in C.

When trying to replace it in gedit:

[image: pre-replacement]

I get this outcome:

[image: post-replacement]

Clearly gedit (version 3.18.3, running on my Ubuntu 16.04) is treating the New Line escape character as an excuse to actually spit out a new line.

Is this a known bug? It's an edge case, and I probably would have never even thought about it if I could write an escape character properly, but still - it made me curious as to what can be done to solve it.

I've tried parentheses, commas, one quotemark, two quotemarks.... no cigar.

*The code itself is just an overly-tedious `switch` exercise from a book, LCTHW by Zed A. Shaw.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gedit simply interprets the `\n` as newline character, which is correct and useful in my opinion, because it allows you to replace something with real line breaks.

To stop that and replace something with `\n` literally, you have to escape the backslash with another backslash and type `\\n` instead in the "Replace with" text field.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\\n` instead of `\n` in **Replace with** field

[image]